# Snapping drawn rectangles to each other

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have a WPF application, wherein I draw rectangles in a canvas.I need to add a functionality in which when i draw a rectangle if there is a rectangle next to it (for eg: suppose first rectangle x coordinate is 236 and second rectangle coordinate is 235) i need to snap the second rectangle x coordinate to 236 as shown in the image.
[image]
The snap would be done only if the distance difference is 10.

I have written the following code to do this.

```
private void Canvas_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {                        
          startPos = e.GetPosition(Canvas);
           System.Windows.Point curPosition = e.GetPosition(SectionCanvas);
           rect = new System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle
           {
               Stroke = brushColor,
               StrokeDashArray = new DoubleCollection { 2, 2 },
               Tag = "rectangle"
           };     
        Canvas.SetLeft(rect, startPos.X);
                Canvas.SetTop(rect, startPos.X);
                SectionCanvas.Children.Add(rect);
         }

 private void Canvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

                currentPos = e.GetPosition(SectionCanvas);

                var x = Math.Min(currentPos.X, startPos.X);
                var y = Math.Min(currentPos.Y, startPos.Y);

                var w = Math.Max(currentPos.X, startPos.X) - x;
                var h = Math.Max(currentPos.Y, startPos.Y) - y;

                rect.Width = w;
                rect.Height = h;

                Canvas.SetLeft(rect, x);
                Canvas.SetTop(rect, y);

        }

   private void Canvas_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {                                   
              if(rect == null)
              {
                  MessageBox.Show("Could not capture section, Please try again");
                  return;
              }
              endPos = e.GetPosition(SectionCanvas);
              IEnumerable<Rect> coordinates = rectCollection.Select(r => new Rect(Canvas.GetLeft(r), Canvas.GetTop(r), r.Width, r.Height));
              Rect newCordinates = new Rect(Canvas.GetLeft(rect), Canvas.GetTop(rect), rect.Width, rect.Height);                   
              if (coordinates.Any(c => c.IntersectsWith(newCordinates)))))
              {
                  MessageBox.Show("New Rectangle intersects with existing rectangle");
                  Canvas.Children.Remove(rect);
                  return;
              }
              rectCollection.Add(rect);
              rect = null;    

              foreach(Point p in tempCollection)
                    {
                        if((startPos.X <= (p.X + 10) && startPos.X >= (p.X -10)))
                        {
                            startPos.X = p.X;
                        }
                        if(endPos.X <= (p.X + 10) && endPos.X >= (p.X - 10))
                        {
                            var x1 = Math.Max(endPos.X,p.X) - Math.Min(endPos.X, p.X);
                            var w1 = startPos.X - x1;
                            endPos.X = p.X;
                            startPos.X = w1;
                        }
                        if ((startPos.Y <= (p.Y + 10) && startPos.Y >= (p.Y - 10)))
                        {
                            startPos.Y = p.Y;
                        }

                        if (endPos.Y <= (p.Y + 10) && endPos.Y >= (p.Y - 10))
                        {
                            var x1 = Math.Max(endPos.Y, p.Y) - Math.Min(endPos.Y, p.Y);
                            var w1 = startPos.Y - x1;
                            endPos.Y = p.Y;
                        }
                    }
                    var x = Math.Min(currentPos.X, startPos.X);
                    var y = Math.Min(currentPos.Y, startPos.Y);

                    var w = Math.Max(currentPos.X, startPos.X) - x;
                    var h = Math.Max(currentPos.Y, startPos.Y) - y;

                    rect.Width = w;
                    rect.Height = h;

                    rect.Stroke = Brushes.Coral;

                    Canvas.SetLeft(rect, x);
                    Canvas.SetTop(rect, y);
                    rect = null;
                    tempCollection.Add(startPos);
                    tempCollection.Add(endPos);
            }
```

The above code doesnt work when I am changing the endpoints values. While debugging I can see that the end point value changes but the rectangle drawn doesn't change. I am not able to find out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I swear I saw a question just like this here yesterday.  Is this a Microsoft interview question or something?

Comment: @McGarnagle : You saw a question like this ok fine. did that question was answered?? If so where is the link??

Comment: Why this question is downvoted?? If this is an already existing question then paste the link. and the answer will be useful for the OP and others. Do not downvote Without having a proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer which was a dumb mistake from my end.

While calculating the width and height after snapping, I am using currentPos, instead I should use endPos.

```
 var x = Math.Min(endPos.X, startPos.X);
 var y = Math.Min(endPos.Y, startPos.Y);

 var w = Math.Max(endPos.X, startPos.X) - x;
 var h = Math.Max(endPos.Y, startPos.Y) - y;
```